# How do I set different front pages for domain access sub sites?

Tags: domain-access

I am using the [Domain Access module](http://drupal.org/project/domain) and would like to have two distinct front pages. The primary one works as expected, and I have a separate front page template. The secondary domain front page is not picking up the front page template; instead, it is displaying the breadcrumbs and heading just like the secondary pages.

How do I configure the module so that the secondary domain picks up the front page template?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention versions, so I will assume the most recent: Drupal 7 and Domain Access 7.x-3.9.

The preferred method requires that your 'secondary front page', as you call it, has a different path than your primary front page.

Make sure the Domain Settings module (part of the Domain Access package) is enabled. This will allow you to specify domain-specific configuration options on several admin forms.

Now, when you go to /admin/config/system/site-information, you will see a fieldset at the bottom of the page saying "Domain-specific settings". Choose the domain for which you want a different front page. Under "Default front page" higher up the form, enter the path of your secondary front page and click the save button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the answer above answer the question. The problem is not to define several frontpage. The problem is that he want to change the template depending on the domain.

So I think he would like to have several page.tpl.php files, one for each domain, to be able to remove breadcrumb and things he don't want on one of this domain.